# Convert BitmapImage to SoftwareBitmap in UWP

Tags: uwp, type-conversion, bitmapimage

I need to find out how to convert a BitmapImage object into a SoftwareBitmap in order to save it to a file without losing resolution as I would do with RenderTargetBitmap.

I have the following situation:

```
private void TakePic() {
    BitmapImage currentImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://.../image.jpg"));
    ImageControl.Source = currentImage;
}

private void SavePic() {
    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(...);
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
        encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap();
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

I can't use RenderTargetBitmap on ImageControl because my image from url is way bigger than the ImageControl size. With RenderTargetBitmap I would shrink my output to the size of this control.

Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: Hi. I noticed that the purpose of your image conversion is to save the image locally. Then you can try to use `HttpClient` to download images, and there is no need to do image conversion.

Comment: The problem with this is that the moment the user decides to save the image he previewed in the ImageControl, may no longer exist in the server because I have a continuous "image stream" on the server and an API that lets me download an image in a specific time. However it lets download only the images of the last n seconds. If the user takes the pic of the (n + 1)th second it is no longer available. I don't know if I'm being able to explain myself

Comment: I know. So I can assume that you only have one chance to get an image from the link. I understand why you want to use `SoftwareBitmap`, but you seem to have doubts about how to convert `BitmapImage` to `SoftwareBitmap`. Can I give my solution?

Comment: Sure, I will always listen to solutions that may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that since we have the need to save the image locally, we can properly allocate some system resources to save the image stream.

Since we need `SoftwareBitmap`, we don't have to use `BitmapImage` as the source of the Image.

Here is my test code:

```cs
SoftwareBitmap CacheBitmap = null;

public TestPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    SetImageSource();
}

public async void SetImageSource()
{
    // Load image from web
    WebRequest myrequest = WebRequest.Create("http://.../image.jpg");
    WebResponse myresponse = myrequest.GetResponse();
    var imgstream = myresponse.GetResponseStream();

    // Try to create SoftwareBitmap
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imgstream.CopyTo(ms);
    var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(ms.AsRandomAccessStream());
    var softBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

    // Use SoftwareBitmapSource to ImageSource
    var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
    await source.SetBitmapAsync(softBitmap);
    TestImage.Source = source;

    // Keep reference
    CacheBitmap = softBitmap;
}
```

When you need to save image, you can use this `SoftwareBitmap`:

```cs
private void SavePic() {
    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(...);
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
        encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(CacheBitmap);
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Note.

When we initially use Uri as the image source, the download is done inside the Image. We can't get the image source as source stream, so we can extract the download process to the outside, so that we can control the original data stream.

Best regards.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for! Another workaround I came to before this was to save the image as a file named temp.jpg as soon as  the user takes the picture and overwriting it everytime he takes another one. When hit save the Temp.jpg would be renamed to foo.jpg.

Anyway this solution is perfect. Thank you very much for this.